# Group theory Normal subgroup of a group

Tags: group-theory

If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Show that if $g_{1}$ and $g_{2}$ are elements of the group G, then $(g_{1}H)(g_{2}H)=(g_{1}g_{2})H$.

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: what is true of the left and right cosets of a normal subgroup?

Comment: Isn't $gH=Hg$ while $H$ is normal subgroup in $G$?

Comment: they are identical: Hg=gH for every element g in G

Comment: Precisely. Now what can you say about the expression $(g_{1}H)(g_{2}H)$...? :)

Comment: Well because G is a group, the brackets don't matter so it is equal to: g1Hg2H and because Hg2= g2H you can write g1g2HH and can you then say that HH is just simply H? Because then I'll have the answer, but I think it's kind of strange to say that HH = H

Comment: That looks like a good way to go to me. Make sure your write up is precise but what you are thinking looks correct to me.

Comment: Indeed, $HH =H$. Think about subgroups - why should this be true?

Comment: Yes thank you, but how can you write it down "precisly"? It there a special way to prove this?

Comment: I just mean that perhaps it is best to avoid saying things of the flavor "because $G$ is a group, the brackets don't matter"; instead, you might consider writing "because $G$ is a group, the group operation is associative and therefore...". Perhaps that is just my opinion though. As for how to prove $HH =H$, think about the properties of a group - this should be true for any group, and you can perhaps see this using the existence of an identity element and closure under the group operation. Try to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Let $h_1$, $h_2 \in H$ arbitrary. Then $g_1h_1g_2h_2 = g_1g_2(g_2^{-1}h_1g_2)h_2 \in g_1g_2H$, since $H$ is normal and hence $g_2^{-1}h_1g_2 \in H$. Conversely, $g_1g_2h_1 = (g_1e)( g_2h_1) \in g_1Hg_2H$, where $e$ denotes the identity element of $G$.